# The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) Integer, int

Tags: java, random, primes

My coding is to create 100 prime numbers randomly in a range of 1 to 1000, but I got an error message `The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) Integer, int` at

```
Integer date;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    date = new Integer(value.nextInt(1000));
    if(date > 1 && prime(date) != -1)`
        tree.add(date);
}
```

I guess it yields error since We cannot say integer > 1? But then how should we say it?

And for`prime(date) != -1)`, I'm not clear for what does it mean, look like unnecessary.

Comment: What is the backquote here : `if(date > 1 && prime(date) != -1)'` ? What version of Java you use ?

Comment: your code is incomplete. The check for prime(date)!=-1 means that the method prime(Integer x) return -1 if the number is not prime. So you check that the return number is not -1, this makes sure your number is a prime number, and then you add it to your tree.

Comment: The > operator is OK, I think you're using the method prime(date) without even declaring it/or having access  and the error is there. Why do you call the variable date?? isn't it better to call it number?. Then your inserting the primes in a list called tree... call it primes!

Comment: @NicolasAlbert Java 7

Comment: @Alboz Then it means I should set before it shows -1 when when the number is not prime?

Comment: @Alboz So now it looks like that?`int number;
 int count = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
 {
  number = new int(value.nextInt(1000));
  if(number > 1 && primes(date) != -1)
   tree.add(date);
 }`

Comment: @NicolasAlbert Yes, why asking?

Comment: @Vivi check your project `Properties` , `Java compiler` and look the `Compiler compliance level` value. If it is `1.4`, set a value at least `1.5`.

Comment: @Vivi on your last comment code you are passing to the prime() method the variable date which is undefined (not declared). And you also adding it to the list (called tree). It won't compile.

Comment: As a note, don't use `new Integer`. Use `Integer.valueOf()` instead if you really need the wrapper class--and here, it's cheaper and simpler to just use an `int`.

Comment: I would use `int date` not Integer given the value can't be `null` and it would solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

The last time that error was produced by a Java compiler was with version 1.4, superseded by 1.5 in the year 2004, when the language specification introduced the autoboxing behavior needed to make your example compile without problems.

I have tried your code with Java 8 and it compiles fine (after adding the obviously missing details).

The solution seems clear: either use a modern Java compiler and do not force it to work in 1.4 compatibility mode, or, if you happen to work on a legacy project, abide by the rules governing the pertinent historical version of Java. The "manual unboxing" method on `Integer` is `intValue()`.

If you happen to be working with Java 8 on a slightly outdated Eclipse, and your project is maven-based, then you may get this issue because the m2e plugin doesn't recognize version 1.8 and falls back to its default, which is 1.4. In that case I advise upgrading to the newest Eclipse (Luna).

Comment: I upvoted, but you could actually mention in the answer what are the rules that OP should obey - either intValue() or variable of type int would probably all that is needed here, given OP would want to work with pre-5 java.

Comment: @eis I've done something better than that: offer a possible cause of OP's problem under the likely assumption that he is *not* really working on a Java 1.4 project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are for some reason bound to an earlier version of Java, try `date.intValue() > 1`